# Choosing path of packet in socket programming?

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming

Would it be possible to manually set or at least influence the path that a packet takes through the internet using socket programming for an application?

For e.g. suppose I don't want the program to send packets that go through routers based in country A, but to go around it instead.

Would that be possible? I am using C++ so advice in that context would be great but any language would be helpful as well.

Comment: The ARP (ping) protocol may give you some hints. The `traceroute` command certainly does with a Linux system.

Comment: traceroute doesn't do that.

Comment: From the source computer you can influence the route to the first hop. After that each router decides the best path.

Comment: That would not be possible using either TCP or UDP. This is based on the the routers you encounter on your way. Modern routers usually have interfaces which allow to configure them remotely, but somehow I doubt this is what you are looking for.

Comment: The IPv4 [source route option](http://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos12.1/topics/concept/reconnaissance-deterrence-attack-evasion-ip-source-route-understanding.html) may be able to do this. I don't know enough about it to say whether it works in practice is ignored. From my very quick research it appears that some (many? most?) routers block packets with this option set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No.**

The whole point of packet-switched networks is that routing is determined collectively by the router located at each hop along the way. That is why they are called routers. It's fundamental to how a network as large as the internet can actually work in any useful way at all.

The originating machine does not and cannot hope to have enough information to decide on an inter-country network route and, even if it did, the rest of the internet would never abide by its decision.

Whatever bizarre and/or nefarious use you have in mind for this, you'll have to think of alternatives.